# stuck on decoding a variable

Tags: javascript, binary, decode, binary-data

I'm gonna get bunch of down votes for this but I don't know anything about binary and I came across something that I need to decode it, here:

```
tst;
tst = 501511502 << 64;
tst |= 485000121 << 32;
tst |= 100001250;
```

can someone help me on how i'd go about doing this?
thank you and sorry for the dumb question i didn't have the time to go and learn about binary.

Comment: I don't think you can decode this. When you use bitwise `OR` with a `1` bit, the result is `1` regardless of the input.

Comment: @Barmar i edited the code, what about now? possible?

Comment: Now the numbers are exceeding JavaScript's precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting by 64 bits exceeds JavaScript's numeric precision. But if it could hold numbers like that, you would decode it by right-shifting and masking:

```
number1 = tst >> 64 & 0xffffffff; // 501511502
number2 = tst >> 32 & 0xffffffff; // 485000121
number3 = tst & 0xffffffff; // 100001250
```

`0xffffffff` is a mask for a 32-bit field of the number.

Comment: sorry i can't understand this, what should i put for `tst` ?

Comment: `tst` is the result of the code you posted.

Comment: then what is 0xffffffff ?

Comment: That masks 32 bits.

Comment: thank you very much this worked but i have an other case that the `tst` numbers are longer and i think the 0xffffffff doesn't work for them, what should i do about larger numbers? do you have a source for these masks you could share?

Comment: JavaScript only supports 32 bits for bitwise operations. You can't do this with larger numbers.